# How do I create a lowercase i with a combining accent mark that does not replace the i's dot in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode

I need to type a regular lowercase i and a barred-i with a tilde above the i's dot, like these:

[image: sample with tildes above dots]

When I do this in Word (using v 16.16.11 for Mac), when it combines the accent mark with the letter 'i', it replaces the i's dot with the accent mark, thus:

[image: sample with tildes replacing dots]

The combined unicode character for regular i is U+0129. I have typed these using the character viewer. I have the phonetic alphabet and IPA fonts installed. The combining tilde is U+0303, barred i is U+0268.

(I know my desired result looks terrible, but I am writing about a language in which lower case i and small-caps ɪ are both used, and it is crucial to distinguish between them. The dotless versions look too close to a small caps ɪ.)

Comment: Do you have the Word auto-correct options disabled? It might be converting to a target language based on your Word configuration. My pretty much out-of-the-box Word recognizes Alt+0303 on Windows as your expected output.

Comment: Have you confirmed these characters exist in any character set?

Comment: Auto-correct is disabled. Diacritics just seem to behave differently on Windows & Mac. For me, all the fonts noted in the comments behave the same (replaces dot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Letter ***i***
- U+0307 Combining Dot Above
- U+0303 Combining Tilde

Comment: what about barred I U+0268, I guess he'd use the combining dot above (U307), followed by U+303(combining tilda)?